# Asp.Identity with an existing Users table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

i need to prepare an MVC 5 application with an existing tbl_users table for members. Can i use or modify Asp.Identity or need to prepare a custom membership? 
Please advise.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_user](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [password_raw] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [url] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [language] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [active] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [session_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [reg_date] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [theme] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [timezone] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [last_visit_date] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [past_visit_date] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [activation] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [activation_date] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [ip_address] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [security_question] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [security_answer] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [lock_url] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [lock_is_locked] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [lock_time] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [change_password] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [last_change_password_date] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [expire_date] [date] NULL,
    [employee_no] [bigint] NULL,
    [student_no] [bigint] NULL,
    [parent_no] [bigint] NULL,
    [user_type] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [last_site] [varchar](50) NULL
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive your custom user class from IUser and define properties (extras) there. Something like this:

```
public class IdentityUser: IUser
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdentityUser"/> class
    /// </summary>
    public IdentityUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Roles = (ICollection<IdentityUserRole>)new List<IdentityUserRole>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IdentityUser"/> class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">Username for the user</param>
    public IdentityUser(string username): this()
    {
        UserName = username;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IUser<string> members
    // Custom properties...
    #endregion
}
```

You can find more information here: https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/decoupling-asp-net-identity-2-0-from-entity-framework-in-mvc5-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the help; i am working on it:

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(IdentityModel.Configurations.IdentityUserConfiguration).Assembly);         
}

IdentityModel is causing problem, couldnt be found, 

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

is also added.

Comment: IdentityModel is the name of the assembly. It seems that your IdentityUserConfigur‌​ation.cs file is defined in the IdentityModel assembly in the IdentityModel.Configurations namespace. You need to import that assembly in your project. Or correct the namespace in your OnModelCreating method